# Store file in Restlet put method

Tags: java, restlet, put

I'm trying to store a file which is sent via PUT to a Restlet resource.

The curl statement looks like this:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:8080/EAIConfig/ri/media" --data-binary img019.png
```

And this is my resource implementation:

```
@Override
protected Representation put(Representation entity) throws ResourceException {
    try {
        InputStream in = entity.getStream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Temp/media-file.png");
        IOUtils.copy(in,out);
        out.close();
        in.close();         
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new EmptyRepresentation();
}
```

This runns without errors. But the resulting `/Temp/media-file.png` does contain the name of the sent file instead of the sent image data.

Any idea how to get the file contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a problem in your Restlet code but rather in the way you call it using curl.

You forget the '@' in the parameter `--data-binary`. You should use something like that:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:8080/EAIConfig/ri/media" --data-binary "@img019.png"
```

I made a try with your code and it works for me. I suppose that you the class `IOUtils` from Commons IO.

One small comment. Your method `put` needs to be defined as public and with annotation `@Put` to be directly called by Restlet ;-)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry